# Gradle Task to clone a private git repo in linux

Tags: java, linux, github, gradle, github-actions

I have written a gradle task to clone a repo to a specific directory. Repo is private. The command expects authentication. Now I cannot provide values directly to the URI. Is there a way we can use git apps to authenticate the same and clone the repo.

```
task cloneRepository(type: Exec) {
    def rootDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home")
    def clonedRepoDirectory = "${rootDirectory}/WRETest"
    def clonedRepoDir = file(clonedRepoDirectory)
    if (!clonedRepoDir.exists()) {
        clonedRepoDir.mkdirs()
    }
    def password = "28@biJEN95!"
    def encodedPassword = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")
    def gitURL = "https://Jenith2211:${encodedPassword}@github.com/element5inc/e5-platform-devkit.git"
    commandLine 'git', 'clone', '-b', 'dev', gitURL, clonedRepoDirectory
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by providing values to the URI? The question is unclear.

Comment: @aled  if you could see the code there is github url, where I need to provide the data